# TXM_MODULE_MANAGER_16_MPU for STMEZH7

Tags: threadx, azure-rtos, arm-mpu

According to the application note [AN4838](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00272912-managing-memory-protection-unit-in-stm32-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) page 12, STMEZH7 has only 8 regions.
However, there is the following statement in the project [description of STM32H747I](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/x-cube-azrtos-h7/blob/main/Projects/STM32H747I-DISCO/Applications/ThreadX/Tx_MPU/README.md):

> The TXM_MODULE_MANAGER_16_MPU is a Preprocessor define that should be
> added in both C and Assembly preprocessor define list to allow the
> application on the stm32H7xx family to work properly.

I searched for the symbole to see if it really refers to the MPU configuration of 16 regions instead of 8, and I found the following in the tx_thread_schedule:

```
config_mpu:
    LDM     r0!,{r2-r9}                             // Load MPU regions 0-3
    STM     r1,{r2-r9}                              // Store MPU regions 0-3
    LDM     r0!,{r2-r9}                             // Load MPU regions 4-7
    STM     r1,{r2-r9}                              // Store MPU regions 4-7
#ifdef TXM_MODULE_MANAGER_16_MPU
    LDM     r0!,{r2-r9}                             // Load MPU regions 8-11
    STM     r1,{r2-r9}                              // Store MPU regions 8-11
    // Regions 12-15 are reserved for the user to define.
    LDM     r0,{r2-r9}                              // Load MPU regions 12-15
    STM     r1,{r2-r9}                              // Store MPU regions 12-15
#endif
```

I have tried to remove the symbol for a project with STM32H735, but it gives unexpected behaviour. **Does this means the AN is wrong and we can configure 16 regions and which also means we can configure 128 (16*8) subregions ?**

**EDIT:** after the response from the linked manual P254,
Removing the TXM_MODULE_MANAGER_16_MPU to indicate it has 16 regions results in unexpected behavior,
the MPU_TYPE.DREGION= 0x10 which also indicates 16 regions,
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app note is unclear
[image: screenshot of app note]

Edit: The STM32H7xx chips should all have 8 region MPUs according to the programming guide https://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/pm0253-stm32f7-series-and-stm32h7-series-cortexm7-processor-programming-manual-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: 8/16 (1)(2) shouldn't be respectively so that first part 8 referring to first part in reference (1)?

Comment: Looking at the programming manual for the H7, it states that there are only 8 MPU regions.  https://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/pm0253-stm32f7-series-and-stm32h7-series-cortexm7-processor-programming-manual-stmicroelectronics.pdf